# Centering text (link) inside div

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink, center

for some reason my text (link) is being pushed outside of the div container. I am wanting the text to be inside the div, and JUST the text to me clickable, not the entire div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="title">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Work</a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title {

  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 15em;
}

.title a {

  height: 15em;
  font-size: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
}
```

When Inspecting in a browser, the '' is extremely large for some reason.

Thanks.

```css
.title {

  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 15em;
}

.title a {

  height: 15em;
  font-size: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inknut+Antiqua" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="title">
   <a href="http://www.google.com">Work</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line-height for a font that is 150px is very large and is causing the overflow.  Play around with line-height to get the effect you desire:

```
.title a {
  height: 15em;
  font-size: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srza8bhk/

Answer (score 0):

remove `height:15em` from anchor tag. and  set it's `line-height` should be less

like:

```
.title a {
  font-size: 150px;
  line-height: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
 }
```